# connection between called times of map() function and the number of map tasks emited in a MR Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I wrote a MR programme to estimate PI(3.141592.........) as followed, but I encounted a problem:

The num of map tasks emited by the framework is 11 and following is the output(35 lines in total).But I expected the output was 11 lines. is there anything i miss?

INCIRCLE    78534096
INCIRCLE    78539304
INCIRCLE    78540871
INCIRCLE    78537925
INCIRCLE    78537161
INCIRCLE    78544419
INCIRCLE    78537045
INCIRCLE    78534861
INCIRCLE    78545779
INCIRCLE    78528890
INCIRCLE    78540007
INCIRCLE    78542686
INCIRCLE    78534539
INCIRCLE    78538255
INCIRCLE    78543392
INCIRCLE    78543191
INCIRCLE    78540938
INCIRCLE    78534882
INCIRCLE    78536155
INCIRCLE    78545739
INCIRCLE    78541807
INCIRCLE    78540635
INCIRCLE    78547561
INCIRCLE    78540521
INCIRCLE    78541320
INCIRCLE    78537605
INCIRCLE    78541379
INCIRCLE    78540408
INCIRCLE    78536238
INCIRCLE    78539614
INCIRCLE    78539773
INCIRCLE    78537169
INCIRCLE    78541707
INCIRCLE    78537141
INCIRCLE    78538045

//porgramme starts
import ...

public class PiEstimation {

```
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

            private final static Text  INCIRCLE             = new Text("INCIRCLE");
            private final static LongWritable TimesInAMap   = new LongWritable(100000000);
            private static Random random = new Random();

            public  class MyPoint {
                    private double  x = 0.0;
                    private double  y = 0.0;

                    MyPoint(double _x,double _y) {
                            this.x = _x;
                            this.y = _y;
                    }

                    public boolean inCircle() {
                            if ( ((x-0.5)*(x-0.5) + (y-0.5)*(y-0.5)) <= 0.25 )
                                    return true;
                            else
                                    return false;
                    }

                    public void setPoint(double _x,double _y) {
                            this.x = _x;
                            this.y = _y;
                    }
            }
            public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                            long i = 0;
                            long N = TimesInAMap.get();
                            MyPoint myPoint = new MyPoint(random.nextDouble(),random.nextDouble());
                            long sum = 0;
                            while (i < N ) {
                            if (myPoint.inCircle()) {                                           
                                sum++;
                            }
                            myPoint.setPoint(random.nextDouble(),random.nextDouble());
                            i++;
                            }
                            output.collect(INCIRCLE, new LongWritable(sum));
                            }
            }


    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<LongWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      long sum = 0;
      while (values.hasNext()) {
        //sum += values.next().get();
        output.collect(key, values.next());
      }
      //output.collect(key, new LongWritable(sum));
  }
  }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  JobConf conf = new JobConf(PiEstimation.class);
  conf.setJobName("PiEstimation");

  conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

  conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
  conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
  conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

  conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
  conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
  conf.setNumMapTasks(10);
  conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

  JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of map tasks launched is determined by a number of things - mainly the input format, it's associated block size to chunk the input files up into and whether the input files themselves are 'splittable'

Separately, the number of times map is called, depends on the number of records in each map split (the data the mapper is processing).

Say you have a single 100 line text file for input - most probably this will be processed by a single Mapper, but the map method is called 100 times - once for each line in the input file

If you count the number of lines in your input file - that is the amount of times map will be called across all Mappers. It's difficult to determine exactly how many times map will be called in each Mapper.